# How to add styling exceptions to 3rd item in am unordered list

Tags: css, styles, html-lists

I have a navigation area that has buttons created using an unordered list. I am trying to make the button that is clicked have different styling properties than the rest of the list when it appears on the linked page. However, adding a different "style" or "id" does not seem to work when applied to the list item. How can I single out the one item and style it differently than the rest of the list?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to target the elements other than the 3rd `li` inside an unordered list (`ul`), you can use something like:

```
ul li:not(:nth-child(3)​) {
    /*Your CSS*/
}
```

And of course, you can target that specific element with:

```
ul li:nth-child(3) {
     /*Your CSS*/
}
```

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/cCeHV/)

Comment: so if you specified an "id" for the list would you just swap ul with the normal #name?